# Plot time series knowing only start time/date and sampling periods

Tags: r

I want to plot a density time series with following data:

density vector (4,2,5,8,4,6,4)
sampling period vector (unit: seconds) (2,2,2,2,3,2,2)

as you can see, the sampling period is not constant. I only know the starting date and time.

I somehow need to assign the start time date to the first measurement and then compute the following dates and times for the following measurements, but i don't know how exactly to code it.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting first the desired vector in a ts, provided an initial starttime and period's cumsum.
I assumed that you sample a continous process (there are not spanned/death times)

```
require (lubridate)
require (tidyr)
require (ggplot2)
require (ggfortify)
require (timetk)


density <- c (4,2,5,8,4,6,4)
seconds <- c (2,2,2,2,3,2,2)
starttime <- 0
time <- 0 + cumsum (seconds)

df <- as.data.frame (cbind (time, seconds, density))
df$time <- as_datetime(df$time)
df$ts <- tk_ts (df, select = density)

autoplot (df$ts, ts.geom = 'bar', fill = 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot the density against the cumulative sum of the seconds added to the start.

```
dens <- c(4,2,5,8,4,6,4)
secs <- c(2,2,2,2,3,2,2)
st <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00")

plot(st + cumsum(secs), dens, xlab = "", type = "l")
```